# Follow Maintenance Manual or Service technician recommendations?

Tags: pcv-valve

We have a 2006 Highlander. Whenever we take it for regular servicing, the service technician recommends some items not specified in the maintenance manual. We told him that and he said it is common for the maintenance manual to not indicate all the items needed. For example, he recommends PCV valve replacement and fuel injection service which is not there in the manual. What recommendation should we follow?

Comment: Why did he recommend the PCV replacement (is the one on the car blocked/stuck?) and why did he suggest an "injection service" and what would be part of the injection service?

Answer (score 2):

Take Timo's advice.  If it 'aint broke, don't fix it.  If it's not a scheduled service item, don't mess with it unless you've actually got a problem.